# malloc succeeds after failing with no free

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I wrote a tiny program to get a rough estimate of the heap size (I know I could probably have just googled it, but this seemed more fun and I thought it would be a quick simple thing).

This is the whole program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    unsigned long long alloc_size = 1024;
    unsigned long long total = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    void* p = 0;

    while(alloc_size >= 16) {
        p = malloc(alloc_size);
        if (p) {
            total += alloc_size;
            i++;
            printf("%u)\tAllocated %llu bytes\tTotal so far %llu\n", i, alloc_size, total);
            alloc_size *= 2;
        }
        else {
            alloc_size /= 2;
        }
    }
    printf("Total alloctions: %llu bytes in %u allocations", total, i);
}
```

I ran this, and was surprised by 2 things:

1. The results were inconsistent. If I run it multiple times, I don't get exactly the same result. Thanks to the virtual memory model (or whatever it is called), shouldn't this be deterministic?
2. Since the program never frees memory, I would expect that if a malloc for a certain size fails once, it will not suddenly succeed later, but - surprise! Here is a sample from one run of the program, Other times I got different (see #1) but similar results:

```
42)     Allocated 65536 bytes   Total so far 28337044480
43)     Allocated 16384 bytes   Total so far 28337060864
44)     Allocated 16384 bytes   Total so far 28337077248
45)     Allocated 16384 bytes   Total so far 28337093632
46)     Allocated 16384 bytes   Total so far 28337110016
47)     Allocated 32768 bytes   Total so far 28337142784
48)     Allocated 8192 bytes    Total so far 28337150976
49)     Allocated 8192 bytes    Total so far 28337159168
50)     Allocated 16384 bytes   Total so far 28337175552
51)     Allocated 32768 bytes   Total so far 28337208320
52)     Allocated 65536 bytes   Total so far 28337273856
53)     Allocated 131072 bytes  Total so far 28337404928
54)     Allocated 262144 bytes  Total so far 28337667072
55)     Allocated 16384 bytes   Total so far 28337683456
56)     Allocated 8192 bytes    Total so far 28337691648
57)     Allocated 4096 bytes    Total so far 28337695744
```

As you can see, this is after it already reached the peak allocation size and is on it's way down. Between allocations #42 and #43, it would have tried to allocate 32768 bytes and failed. Same after each of allocations #43 - #45. So how did it suddenly manage it at #47? You can see the same thing at #50 - #54. And this is only a sample. This same behavior happened multiple times in the total of 272 allocations in this particular run.

I hope this was not to long, but I am really confused and would be glad for any light shed on this.

**EDIT**
I should add that this is on a Win7 64bit machine with mingw-w64 64bit gcc compiler, no compiler flags

Comment: Why would `malloc()` fail? And why wouldn't it succeed after some other process has "`free`d" memory? Please explain *exactly the same result*?

Comment: @iharob `malloc` would fail if it couldn't allocate the required amount of memory (out of memory). The virtual memory model (if I understand it correctly) means that my programs memory allocations are completely isolated from other programs'.

Comment: That will likely not work on modern OS (see "optimistic allocation"). Even if, it does not guarantee it will be available lateron. Just allocate what you need and fail if not available. Don't try to outsmart your OS.

Comment: You should modify your program to write to the newly allocated memory and then rerun your program.  The memory writing forces the system to allocate the actual pages.  It may alter the behaviour if the system has an optimistic allocation strategy.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No change. Still weird, though much slower

Comment: It takes a while to write to 28 GiB of memory, which is roughly what your numbers say it is using.  It might be having to write the data to disk to cover for the difference between your virtual memory and the physical memory.  Your code clearly leaks memory — if you kept a record of previous allocations (start pointer and block size) and scribbled on each block each time you allocated space, you'd probably see an even more dramatic slowdown. The usable space is a lot smaller than the allocatable space — unless you have the luxury of 32 GiB main memory on your machine (which is not impossible).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know this. This is why I am confused, since the whole thing is only virtual address space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Windows, a memory allocation (commit) will succeed if there is enough paging file space to back it.  The amount of space available in the paging file can change due to actions by other processes reserving and releasing memory.

On Windows, malloc is a thin wrapper around HeapAlloc, which is built on VirtualAlloc.

VirtualAlloc will allow you to reserve and/or commit memory.

- **Reserving** means setting aside a range of the process's virtual address space.  A reservation succeeds if the range of virtual addresses is available.  It doesn't mean that memory is available, just that those addresses won't be used for anything else.
- **Committing** means setting aside spacing in the paging file.  A commit succeeds if the paging file has enough free space to back the commit.

Accessing reserved but not-yet-committed memory is an error and will probably crash.

Accessing committed memory may trigger page faults, which the system handles by mapping those pages to actual RAM.  If necessary, some RAM will be copied out to the paging file (which is guaranteed to have enough space because the commit succeeded), and then that RAM is re-purposed for the access that originally triggered the page fault.  Thus accessing committed memory always succeeds.

Windows Heaps use VirtualAlloc (and related functions) under the hood.  Internally, a heap starts with an initial reservation, only part of which is committed.  A HeapAlloc can fail if:  (1) it exhausts its initial reservation or (2) it can't commit more pages because there isn't enough free space in the paging file.  When it succeeds, HeapAlloc returns pointers to committed memory, so accessing memory from a successful HeapAlloc always succeeds.

Since malloc is just a thin wrapper on HeapAlloc, the preceding paragraph applies to malloc as well.

There's an extra wrinkle in that HeapAlloc handles large allocations separately.  I'm not sure if these come from its initial reservation or if they're distinct blocks.

The behavior of baruch's program suggests that it's running into the limit of available memory in the paging file.  The available space in the paging file normally varies as other processes go about their business, so it's not surprising to seem some allocations fail and others succeed as you're near this limit.

Also, the system might adjust the size of the paging file based on perceived demand, policy, and available disk space.  So if you hit the limit once, but try again later, you might find that the limit is higher.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `malloc`, what actually happens is that you're allocating virtual memory. Once you try to access that memory, it triggers the OS (kernel) to allocate the actual, physical memory and map the *actual* memory address onto that virtual address (your pointer).
Most, if not all, modern systems will gladly return a pointer even though the memory is, at the time you call `malloc` not available. Or at least: not available in its required form (ie as a contiguous block of memory).

`malloc` *has* to return a pointer to a contiguous block of memory (if not, pointer arithmetic wouldn't be possible). So say you have 2gigs of memory available, it's very likely that that memory won't be available as a contiguous block, whereas allocating 2 gigs in chunks will work perfectly fine. This can, in part, explain why you see memory being allocated in larger chunks, then all of a sudden, you're allocating the same amount of memory as 2 chunks (because of your dividing the size by 2).

Now, at no particular point are you actually writing to that memory. What you need to understand is that, unless you access this allocated virtual memory, it needn't be mapped to physical memory. Some systems, like Linux, will not allocate physical memory until you actually access the `malloc`'ed block. When this happens, it triggers the kernel to actually go in and allocate physical memory. That physical memory address is than mapped onto the virtual address. This is called *optimistic allocation*.

Because most (if not all) modern system use optimistic allocation, they can allow processes to allocate more memory than is actually available at the time. What matters is that this memory is available by the time the process is actually starting to use it. Something you don't do.

When you call `free` on `malloc`'ed memory that you've never used, all that you actually release is virtual memory. The physical memory remains untouched. If you have written to heap memory, and then call `free`, it's likely that block of memory is not always returned to the system directly (that's not really the job of `free`). Next time you call `malloc`, it's very possible that the newly allocated memory will be taken from the block you just `free`'d. But these are implementation details that would take us too far.

In cases like this, I like to use silly analogies using real-world situations:

`malloc` isn't like planting a flag in a chunk of memory so that nothing else, in any way shape or form is allowed to access that memory. It's more like booking a reservation in a restaurant. Restaurants often over-book, because they expect people not to show up, or to cancel. 99.99% of the time, when you arrive at the restaurant, there will be a table available for you. (the restaurant allocated the table optimistically).

If you don't show up (ie you don't access the memory), the table is available for other people to use. If you did arrive, sat down and ate your dinner (write to memory), you `free` the table by paying the bill and leaving. What the restaurant owner does with the table is not your concern. They might have an outstanding reservation for someone else who will arrive 10 minutes after you left. If so, the restauranteurs allocated the same resource twice, but that didn't cause problems simply because the resource was `free`'d by the time it was needed elsewhere.

This elaborate analogy is, essentially, how and why optimistic allocation works.

Comment: I am aware of this, and that is exactly why I am confused. Since calling `malloc` does not actually reserve physical memory, only a part of the process's virtual address space, so this address space should be 100% available to my process. How then is a new chunk of virtual address space suddenly "found"?

Comment: @baruch: The address space needn't be 100% available. It can be lazily allocated and mapped to physical memory, too. If you use the virtual memory, but not enough _actual_ memory is available, the OOM killer will pay a visit to some (most likely your) process (OOM = Out Of Memory). That's the downside of using optimistic allocation

Comment: What and how your virtual memory is actually mapped onto physical memory is something that is hard to predict, or even accurately explain, given you're on a windows machine. The kernel can swap pages, or simply move change the physical address because it's trying to create a contiguous block of available memory for some process. These things are both implementation defined (the `malloc` implementation details), and platform specific (ie the kernel's memory management model)

Comment: glibc's implementation of `malloc` for example will allocate large chunks of memory (> a page) via `mmap`, and `free`'ing these blocks _will_ return the memory to the system directly to avoid locking large chunks of memory. But again: this is just one possible implementation, there's no way of knowing how other implementations behave in similar situations

Comment: Windows doesn't use optimistic allocation.  It requires that the space being committed can be backed by space in the paging file.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: +1 your answer. It's true that I don't know anything about memory management on windows on a system level, and my rambling about linux' optimistic allocation doesn't really answer the question. I posted it because I figured it might be useful for future reference and it does at least demonstrate that `malloc`'s internal behaviour is strongly platform and implementation dependant. That being said: do you happen to know when, on windows, the allocated memory is actually committed? Does this happen _before_ the allocated memory is written to?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: from MSDN: _"Memory can be committed as little as one page at a time. The maximum amount of memory that can be committed is based solely on the maximum range of contiguous free or reserved addresses (but not a combination of both), regardless of the amount of physical memory available to the system."_ would that allow you to reserve a block of virtual memory that is then later committed in chunks (mapping the virtual pointer to new physical address until a contiguous block of physical memory is available)?

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem:  It depends how you define committed.  In Windows, "committed" means the system has set aside space in the pagefile; it doesn't mean that it's in yet.  In this sense, anything you get back from HeapAlloc or malloc will be committed.  When you first access an allocation, it might not be in RAM, but the system will handle the page fault and make RAM available.  To reserve VM address space without committing, you use VirtualAlloc.  To later access that VM, you first need to commit the page(s) you plan to access, but that commit requires pagefile space, so it can fail.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Operating System has the responsibility to manage the available memory for the user, you cannot expect a linear behaviour of the quantity of memory available at the moment you call your malloc. Between two steps, OS can free an amount of memory doing a swap to the Hard Disk or to another area of the RAM Memory, even if you don't call free explcitly. That's why you expect a failure but malloc is executed with success.

Short answer: OS can free the available memory even if you do not call it.

Comment: No, the OS will not "free" (i.e. reclaim" memory really used by a process. But it might reserve more memory than actually even available in the system on the optimistic approach the process will not really need all pages. Even `calloc` might not help (e.g. copy on write). Modern OSes are quite smart.

Comment: I guess I will disagree a little bit. I was not saying a real free, I said something similar a free, doing a swap for example. It is not a free but is similar.

Comment: Swapping is something completely different. The question is about logical address space of a process. Swapping about physical memory. And after a swap-out, the memory still exists and is allocated to a process. Basically, swap-space is just a different storage-medium, but still part of the physical memory. A modern OS will not even allocate physical memory if a process just requests it. Instead it just sets up the page-tables, tagging the mapped area as not allocated. Only once the process truely accesses the address-space of such a page physical memory is allocated for that page.

Comment: Man, you are trying to explain something that I already know. I am just trying to explain the things in a didatical way.

Comment: 1) Mind your words! I did not offend you, so don't "man" me. 2) From what you wrote it is not clear you really know these details. Maybe you just need to use the correct terms. It is not very didactically to be unclear. Maybe you just oversimplificated.

Comment: Have a nice day, bro. I was not intended to be offensive. I oversimplificated, indeed.